# Copy/Paste Range from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying too simply copy the cells with data in col A of a worksheet to another worksheet at row 2. With the following script the source worksheet name is entered into row 1 of Ave RLD worksheet. If that is all I try to do it will loop through all the worksheets and place their names in the next col of Ave RLD. As soon as I try to copy the data from col A and paste it to Ave RLD I get a Run time error 1004. I left in all the commented lines of things I have been trying. What am I missing?

```
Dim WS_count As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim wksName As String
Dim NumRows As Long

ColNum = 1

Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Ave RLD"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(Trim(ws.Name), 3) = "RLD" Then
        wksName = ws.Name
        NumRows = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox NumRows
        With Worksheets("Ave RLD")
            .Cells(1, ColNum).Value = wksName
            ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NumRows, 1)).Copy
            .Range(Cells(2, ColNum)).Paste.Values
            '.Range(Cells(2, ColNum)).Value = .Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlUp))
            '.Range(Cells(2, ColNum)).Value = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            'MsgBox ws.Cells(1, 26).Value
            '.Cells(2, ColNum).Value = .Worksheets(wksName).Cells(1, 26)
            '.Worksheets(wksName).Cells(1, 1).Copy
            'Worksheets(wksName).Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy
            '.Cells(2, ColNum).Paste
            
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        End With
    End If
Next ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

Lots on this at this site, but this line will error if `ws` is not the active sheet as you do not fully qualify all the ranges

`ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NumRows, 1)).Copy`

And the other line commented below just needs `Range` or `Cells`, also your paste values syntax was off - recording a macro is one way to sort out such details.

```
Dim WS_count As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim wksName As String
Dim NumRows As Long

ColNum = 1

Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Ave RLD"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(Trim(ws.Name), 3) = "RLD" Then
        wksName = ws.Name
        NumRows = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox NumRows
        With Worksheets("Ave RLD")
            .Cells(1, ColNum).Value = wksName
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(NumRows, 1)).Copy 'fully qualify with ws
            .Cells(2, ColNum).PasteSpecial xlpasteValues 'just Cells
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        End With
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Should have recorded a macro ... @BigBen.